# Why are two files reported in RECYCLER when recycle bin is empty?

Tags: windows-xp, filesystems, ntfs, recycle-bin

I have emptied the Recycle Bin.  However, when I right-click on the RECYCLER folder on drive C and select Properties, it says "Contains 2 files, 1 folders".  I see a folder in there with a random number, which I assume is automatically generated by Windows to access the Recycle Bin.  However, I cannot see any files in there.  Why does Properties report two files in RECYCLER?  What are these two files?

Using Windows XP Home SP 3 and NTFS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 REALLY hidden files used to keep track of settings for the Recycle Bin for each user. Explorer does not pick them up, but you can see them by running this command from a command prompt in the \Recycler directory: `dir *.* /ah /s` (the /ah means with attributes of "hidden", and the /s searches sub-directories too).

For more info on the INFO2 file, see this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recycle_Bin_(Windows)#Physical_storage_locations

[image]

Comment: As you can see, I have one folder for each of two users.